# How can I move css elements in jquery from right, from left, from down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When this page scrolled in my website it should do: `table_area-left` moves from left to right to the it's current position, and it should `table_area-right` move  from right to left to the it's current position, and `morph button` move from down to up. I couldn't find jquery code for it; I don't know jquery well. Please help me with it.

I added this jquery-ui library also:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-lCF+55kMUF+3fO/3BiXui4eiUKcQmtr7ecKSeLVDxIQ="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<section id="hizmetlerimiz">
        <!-- hizmetlerimiz sayfası -->
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="genel_icerik">

            <div class="tablo_area-left">
                <h2>RULO AÇMA BOY KESME MAKİNELERİ</h2>
                <p>
                    1,50 mm'den 25.00 mm'ye kadar her tür kalite sıcak ve dekape(RP) grubu malzemeler istenilen
                    her boyda kesilerek servise sunulmaktadır. 0,50 mm'den 3,00 mm'ye kadar tüm soğuk ve
                    galvaniz grubu malzemeler özenle istenilen boyda kesilmekte ve itina ile paketleme yapılmaktadır.
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="tablo_area-right">
                <h2>RULO DİLME MAKİNELERİ</h2>
                <p>
                    0,18 mm'den 2,50 mm'ye kadar her tür soğuk ve galvaniz grubu malzemeler hassas toleranslar dahilinde
                    dilinmekte ve özenle paketleme işlemi yapılmaktadır. 1,50 mm'den 8,00 mm'ye kadar her tür sıcak ve
                    dekape(RP) grubu malzemeler hassas bir işçilikle ve istenilen genişlik toleranslarında dilinmekte ve itina ile
                    paketlenmektedir.
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Table area right end-->
            <div class="morph-button morph-button-overlay morph-button-fixed morph-button">
                <button type="button" style="border-radius:10px; border:inset black; margin-top:50px;" title="Daha Fazla Bilgi">Daha Fazla Bilgi</button>
            </div>
            <!--morp button  -->
        </div>
        <!-- genel icerik end-->
```

Comment: `I dont know well jquery` well, you better start learning. When you post code that you tried and which haven't worked, then we can help you

Comment: Show some effort that you did - questions/answers you read, examples you tried

Comment: I don't ask question. How can I learn jquery. I only the solution way. I don't want you solve it for me. I told for this reason I dont know well jquery. Why you did useless comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like [skrollr](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr), [scrollmagic](http://scrollmagic.io/), [scrollorama](http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrollorama/) etc.